# Selenium - Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium. I generated my first java selenium test case and it has compiled successfully. But when I run that test I got the following RuntimeException

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start <DefaultSelenium.java:88>
```

Kindly tell me how can I fix this error.

This is the java file I want to run.

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import junit.framework.*;

public class orkut extends SeleneseTestCase {

 public void setUp() throws Exception {

  setUp("https://www.google.com/", "*chrome");

 }
 public void testOrkut() throws Exception {

  selenium.setTimeout("10000");

  selenium.open("/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=orkut&hl=en-US&rm=false&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.orkut.com%2FRedirLogin%3Fmsg%3D0&cd=IN&skipvpage=true&sendvemail=false");

  selenium.type("Email", "username");

  selenium.type("Passwd", "password");

  selenium.click("signIn");

  selenium.selectFrame("orkutFrame");

  selenium.click("link=Communities");

  selenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000");

 }

 public static Test suite() {

  return new TestSuite(orkut.class);

 }

 public void tearDown(){

  selenium.stop();

 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {

  junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());

 }

}
```

I first started the selenium server through the command prompt and then execute the above java file through another command prompt.

Second Question: Can I do right click on a specified place on a webpage with selenium.

Comment: Hi! Could you post some code, that show how you are trying to launch the browser (or the config you are using) ? This might help finding out where the problem is coming ;; also : do you have any useful output in the console, coming from Selenium RC ?

Comment: I have added more info to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the last version of Selenium RC (after 1.0) you should change the following:

```
setUp("https://www.google.com/", "*chrome");
```

for

```
setUp("https://www.google.com/", "*firefox");
```

If this doesn't work, try creating a separate firefox profile and using that one:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#specifying-the-firefox-profile

Answer (score 5):

Chances are this problem is caused by an already-running instance of the Selenium server. The new instance needs to listen on the same port number, but can't, because the port is already in use.

Let's say your Selenium server is configured to start on port 4444. Determine if the port is in use using the 'netstat' command:

On Windows: `netstat -an | find "4444"`

Expect to see output like this:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4444           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:4444              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

On Linux, use: `netstat -anp | grep 4444`

(No Linux box to hand, so can't show example output!)

If you see any output, you need to kill the process that's listening on the port that Selenium wants to use. On Windows, use `netstat -anb` to find the process name (it'll be listed after the line specifying the port number). Kill it using the Task Manager. On Linux, the process PID and name will be listed by the command above - kill it using `kill <PID>`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might sound silly but are you sure you have given `selenium.start()` in your code? Beginners can make this mistake.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue, and adding start() fixed the session problem.

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure, `selenium.stop()` method has been called at the end of test steps.

Answer (score 0):

The setUp method basically invokes start method, so don't need to give selenium.start() in above code. I guess this is kind of selenium's bug. it stops testing before it get some response. but I've not found why yet.