# Taking snapshots of different webpages using selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium-rc, webpage-screenshot

I have a list of URLs and I need to take their snapshots . 
I am running selenium server using cmd and running following code in eclipse.

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class MainClass {


    void func(String url, String file)
    {
        Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", url);
        selenium.start();

        selenium.windowMaximize(); 

        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");


        System.out.println("laoded\n");
    //  selenium.wait();
        String file1= "C:\\test\\"+file+".png";
        String file2= "C:\\test\\"+file+"2.png";
        selenium.captureScreenshot(file1);
        selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot(file2, "");

        selenium.stop();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        MainClass demo = new MainClass();

        demo.func("http://www.facebook.com","face"); 

        demo.func("www.reddit.com","reddit"); 

    }
}
```

It's giving  [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XusBv.jpg)

I went through [these links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414934/selenium-could-not-start-selenium-session-failed-to-start-new-browser-session) but couldn't find a solution .
Kindly help me how to fix this . I am new to selenium .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try it like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

alternatively see this link here for a good starting tutorial: http://vishnuagrawal.blogspot.com/2011/12/selenium-taking-screenshot-of-webpage.html

**References:**

- [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Thank you it's working fine but in case of IE it's giving this error http://imgur.com/YYOVy.

Comment: never mind . it's fixed now . I found solution here http://www.testerinyou.blogspot.com/.