# Runtime exception at selenium.start() - Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser

Tags: selenium

Followed this post - 
[Selenium - Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414934/selenium-could-not-start-selenium-session-failed-to-start-new-browser-session)

Error comes up at selenium.start().
I am using selenium rc(2.16) , junit(4.5) in eclipse ide.

The only way to over come this issue is to redeploy our framework in tomcat server, just restart everything.

This is the piece of code that starts selenium

```
private static HttpCommandProcessor proc;
    public static DefaultSelenium selenium;

    if (selenium == null) {

        proc = new HttpCommandProcessor("localhost", 4444, browserName,
                urlName);
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium(proc);
        **selenium.start();**
        selenium.setTimeout(String.valueOf(PAGE_TIMEOUT_TIME));
        selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");
        selenium.deleteAllVisibleCookies();             
    }
```

the selenium server is already started when the execution reaches the above code.

Below is the exception that comes up when execute the tests -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser
  at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:107)
  at <package>.SuperClass.connectToUrl(SuperClass.java:340)
```

Any help or clue to resolve this thing would be appreciated!